# IE7 li with image and text issue - Text . Almost working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm using an unordered list.

With an image to the left and text to the right.

I only noticed today that IE7 was displaying this so badly that it wasn't even acceptable. Woops for not realising sooner.

I have the given the image a class and the text wrapped in a seperate div.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="domain"><img src="http://www.domain.com/img.jpg" alt="img class="footer-thumb" width="40px" height="40px" /></a>
    <div class="recent-post-content">
    <p>day date time</p>
    <p><a title="Content title" href="http://www.domain.com/contentitle &raquo;</a></p>
    </div></li></ul>
```

What's happeninig so far is that it is perfect in every browser except in IE7 where the images are exactly where they should be but the class "recent-post-content" is all pushed up one exactly one image ([li] height) above so the last image doesn't have any text beside it and the first image ([li]) has its "recent-post-content" above it.

I guess it's something simple but after getting this far on my own I thought it best to try and get some advice to fix the last little bit.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try closing the quotes correctly in the img tag (see the alt)?

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but do you have a correct doctype at the top of your document to disable quirks mode?

Comment: it is hilarious to see in title **almost working**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/img.jpg" alt="img class="footer-thumb" width="40px" height="40px" />
```

to

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/img.jpg" alt="img" class="footer-thumb" width="40px" height="40px" />
```

and fix

```
<a title="Content title" href="http://www.domain.com/contentitle &raquo;</a>
```

to

```
<a title="Content title" href="http://www.domain.com/contentitle">&raquo;</a>
```

and IE will behave.

Comment: Closing your tags helps older browsers? Heresy. ;)